# Stable coins differences? (USDC - Coinbase / Circle, GUDS - Gemini, TUSD - Trust Token, PAX - PAXFUL, USDT - Tether)

Tags: coinbase.com, tether, stable-coin

There has been a release of many stables coins recently. What are the differences from each? So far I know that Tether (usdt) is based out of the US banking system and everything else is in the US banking system and regulated. Also I read that the USDC and GUSD has a back door system to freeze and hold accounts if they wanted to. I wasn't sure if PAX had this same thing. What are all the listed pros/cons of each stable coin?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, USDC has a backdoor built in to allow for the freezing and/or seizure of funds if it is believed illicit activity is involved. In other words, any address can be blacklisted and funds frozen. Not very stable for a stable coin, right?

Comment: which stablecoin is the most "stable" out of all of them then?